# Is my evaluation of complex trigonometric expression $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2i\right) -\sin(2i)$ correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Solution: $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2i\right) -\sin(2i)= \\ \frac{1}{2i}\left( e^{-2}\left( \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right) -e^2\left( \cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)  \right) \right) \\ -\frac{e^{-2}}{2i}\left( \cos(0) +i\sin(0)\right)-\frac{e^2}{2i}\left(\cos(0) +i\sin(0)\right) = \\ \frac{e^{-2}}{2i} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i  \right) +\frac{e^{2}}{2i}\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i \right) = \\  (e^{-2}+e^2)  \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i  \right) $$

Firstly, is this the correct solution? Secondly, should I simplify the expression more so that it is in form $x+yi$ or leave it as it is? And also, I know that we can multiply the expression by $i$ to get rid of the $i$ on the denominator, can we do it with any power of $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not correct. Note,

$$\begin{align}
& \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2i\right) -\sin(2i) \\ 
& =\frac{1}{2i}\left( e^{-2}\left( \cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\right) -e^2\left( \cos\frac{\pi}{4}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}  \right) \right) 
-\frac1{2i}\left(e^{-2}-e^{2}\right) \\ 
&=\frac{e^{-2}}{2i} \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i  \right) +\frac{e^{2}}{2i}\left( \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i \right) \\  
&=\frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2} (e^2-e^{-2})+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(e^2+e^{-2}) \right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cosh(2)-i\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\sinh(2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Just one question: Do you multiply $\frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2} (e^2-e^{-2}\right)$ with $i^2$ instead of $i$, so that there wouldn' t be a $\sqrt{-1}$ in front of the expression? But if it' s done to reduce the fraction, there shouldn't apply the rules of $i$ n-th multiplication? But I see, that you have minus sign in front of the last $i$. Can you explain this part?

Comment: $\dfrac {1}{i} \rightarrow \dfrac {i}{i^2} \rightarrow \dfrac {i}{-1} \rightarrow -i.$$